# Parsing date with 'tt' fails on PM

Tags: powershell

ParseExact() works as expected with this AM timestamp. However, it fails on PM.

```
PS C:\Users\pwatson> [DateTime]::ParseExact('11/24/2017 05:12:44.123 AM', 'M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff tt', $null)

Friday, November 24, 2017 05:12:44

PS C:\Users\pwatson> [DateTime]::ParseExact('11/24/2017 05:12:44.123 PM', 'M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff tt', $null)
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:1
+ [DateTime]::ParseExact('11/24/2017 05:12:44.123 PM', 'M/dd/yyyy HH:mm ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

Comment: What culture is your computer set to? Maybe pass in the invariant culture instead of `$null`

Comment: Please edit your question and add culture info. Use `[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread` to get it from Powershell.

Comment: hh instead of HH I think (HH is 24 hour clock and therefore 05:00 pm would be considered invalid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the formatting code `hh` instead of `HH`. `hh` is for 12 hour clocks. HH is for 24 hour clocks. It's working for AM times because 5:12 am is a valid time, but not for PM times 05:25pm is not valid because the 05 is being interpreted as being 5am in the 24 hour clock and therefore incompatible with PM.

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact('11/24/2017 05:12:44.123 AM', 'M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt', $null)
[DateTime]::ParseExact('11/24/2017 05:12:44.123 PM', 'M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt', $null)
```

Returns:

```
24 November 2017 05:12:44
24 November 2017 17:12:44
```